# How can I highlight multiple fields but show a single error message when ActiveRecord validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, user-experience

My use case is that at least one out of two fields needs to be filled in. I'd like to be able to show a single error message but use Rails' built-in error highlighting to identify the fields in question, something along the lines of:

[image: Show a single error message but highlight two fields]

The best approach I've come up with so far is:

- Have a single `:validate` method which checks at least one is present
- If neither is present, it adds three errors:

  - A `:base` error with a custom message
  - `:user_name` and `:email` errors with a custom type that can later be (partially) ignored
- In my view I then need to reject the superfluous messages before displaying the error count or displaying the messages

```rb
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validate :username_or_email_present

  private

  def username_or_email_present
    unless user_name.present? || email.present?
      errors.add(:base, :username_and_email_blank, message: "At least one of User name and Email must be provided")
      errors.add(:user_name, :hide_message_but_highlight_field, message: "no message, this error is just to highlight the field")
      errors.add(:email, :hide_message_but_highlight_field, message: "no message, this error is just to highlight the field")
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/people/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: person) do |form| %>

  <%# Remove the messages from the summary view using `.reject` %>
  <% visible_errors = person.errors.reject{ |e| e.type == :hide_message_but_highlight_field } %>
  <% if visible_errors.any? %>
    <div class="text-red-700">
      <h2><%= pluralize(visible_errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this person from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% visible_errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
    <div class="md:w-1/3">
      <%= form.label :user_name, class: "block text-gray-700 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" %>
    </div>
    <div class="md:w-2/3">
      <%= form.text_field :user_name, required: true, class: "bg-gray-100 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500 focus:ring-0" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
    <div class="md:w-1/3">
      <%= form.label :email, class: "block text-gray-700 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" %>
    </div>
    <div class="md:w-2/3">
      <%= form.email_field :email, required: true, class: "bg-gray-100 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500 focus:ring-0" %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You should probably start by fixing the syntax error at `validate : username_or_email_present`. Symbol literals cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I discovered while writing this question seems to be the least bad solution. I have adopted this solution in my app with a few minor tweaks.

In the model, add a custom `:validate` method and flag the errors with a custom type (I settled on `:highlight_field_but_hide_message`):

```rb
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validate :username_or_email_present

  private

  def username_or_email_present
    if email.blank? && username.blank?
      errors.add(:base, :email_and_username_blank, message: "At least one of Email and Username must be provided")
      errors.add(:email, :highlight_field_but_hide_message)
      errors.add(:username, :highlight_field_but_hide_message)
    end
  end
end
```

In the view, reject the superfluous error messages and then display the remaining errors:

```
# app/views/people/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: person) do |form| %>

  <%# Remove the messages from the summary view using `.reject` %>
  <% visible_errors = person.errors.reject{ |e| e.type == :highlight_field_but_hide_message } %>
  <% if visible_errors.any? %>
    <div class="text-red-700">
      <h2><%= pluralize(visible_errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this person from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% visible_errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  ...

<% end %>
```

Pros:

- This approach leaves all other errors and messages untouched
- It can scale up to as many fields as needed (e.g. if three or more fields are interdependent... although then you might have other usability concerns)
- It's self documenting
- It's fairly consistent with The Rails Way

Cons:

- Additional logic in the view (could potentially be extracted into a ViewComponent)
- Can't custom colour the fields<sup>*</sup> (e.g. to highlight as a warning instead of an error)

<sup>*</sup> You can modify the way Rails tags the error fields by overriding `Rails.application.config.action_view.field_error_proc` but so far in my research I have not seen a way to access the error type from that scope. If we knew the only error on that field was of type `:highlight_field_but_hide_message` we could highlight it with a warning colour instead of an error colour.